# Does the 4D theory of the universe imply that the universe must exist beyond our temporal reference frame?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time

For instance: In order for GR to properly describe gravity, it must invoke a bending of the time axis. The existence of such a dimension and its powerful experimental corroboration must imply that the universe exists outside of our instantaneous temporal reference frame, is this correct?

The implication of this I think is quite terrifying. I can't see how a theory of 4D space-time is compatible in any way with a non-deterministic view of the universe. Where the future extends infinitely into a determined future, the necessary dimension to explain gravity. This would also explain how antimatter particles could exist in a reverse-time direction, since there would be a temporal location for them to exist in prior to it's appearance in our instantaneous temporal reference frame.

edit: by "our instantaneous temporal reference frame". I mean the frame of reference that any observer can have in the universe at any given instant. What a human on earth would perceive as 'right now, this moment'. Which necessarily co-exists with the instantaneous reference frame of any other observer.

So to rephrase, although time flows at different rates for different velocities, all objects in spacetime move at the speed of light through spacetime as a function of temporal velocity + spatial velocity. This doesn't invoke the existence of proper time for an observer beyond the boundary of an instantaneous moment. But the model of gravity itself does, as I discussed above.

Comment: What is an 'instantaneous temporal reference frame', and how does physics describe or deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably gonna find a more interesting answer in a website about Philosophy, but I think there is a physical and mostly objective answer to your question.

Physics does not describe what the Universe is. It only describes a model that matches experiment up to a certain precision. In other words, the fact that GR does uses a four-dimensional spacetime to describe gravity does not imply that spacetime *is* a four-dimensional [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold). It only means that, up to a high level of precision, the Universe behaves as if it was.

As far as I know, the view that the mathematical constructions of a certain theory are indeed real in some sense is known as *realism* (as opposed to [anti-realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-realism#Scientific_anti-realism), which in way general lines is the view that it doesn't have to be so). In General Relativity, it is fairly common, as far as I can tell, for scientists to take the philosophical position that spacetime is indeed something real and it is indeed curved. However, it is important to point out that this is a philosophical position. Hence, GR doesn't necessarily imply so. It's success comes from the fact that it matches experiment, but there is no way to know whether its description is indeed what the Universe *is*.

In short, the answer to your question is  that there are different philosophical viewpoints, each of them giving different answers, but from a purely physical point of view the answer is inconclusive. GR is an excellent description of how the Universe looks like, but does not attempt at describing what the Universe actually is. Whether the two things are related or not is a matter of Philosophy, not of Physics.

**Disclaimer:** One could argue that "Whether the two things are related or not is a matter of Philosophy, not of Physics" is a philosophical viewpoint. This answer definitely bears my own philosophical viewpoints, but I hope the overall content can be understood in spite of it.